# Can you use pytorch for a non-torch optimization problem?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, crf

I would like to use Pytorch to learn the 6 parameters in this small CRF model. I can implement a forward method, loss function and optimizer - but it's unclear how to "tell" pytorch what the parameters of this model are:

```
import numpy as np
import pydensecrf.densecrf as dcrf
import pydensecrf.utils as utils


class DenseCRF(object):
    def __init__(self, iter_max, pos_w, pos_xy_std, bi_w, bi_xy_std, bi_rgb_std):
        self.iter_max = iter_max
        self.pos_w = pos_w
        self.pos_xy_std = pos_xy_std
        self.bi_w = bi_w
        self.bi_xy_std = bi_xy_std
        self.bi_rgb_std = bi_rgb_std

    def __call__(self, image, probmap):
        C, H, W = probmap.shape

        U = utils.unary_from_softmax(probmap)
        U = np.ascontiguousarray(U)

        image = np.ascontiguousarray(image)

        d = dcrf.DenseCRF2D(W, H, C)
        d.setUnaryEnergy(U)
        d.addPairwiseGaussian(sxy=self.pos_xy_std, compat=self.pos_w)
        d.addPairwiseBilateral(
            sxy=self.bi_xy_std, srgb=self.bi_rgb_std, rgbim=image, compat=self.bi_w
        )

        Q = d.inference(self.iter_max)
        Q = np.array(Q).reshape((C, H, W))

        return Q
```

Here is my attempt so far:

```
import torch.nn as nn

class TorchCRF(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, iter_max, pos_w, pos_xy_std, bi_w, bi_xy_std, bi_rgb_std):
        super(TorchCRF, self).__init__()
        self.iter_max  = iter_max
        self.pos_w  = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(pos_w, requires_grad=True))
        self.pos_xy_std  = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(pos_xy_std, requires_grad=True))
        self.bi_w  = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(bi_w, requires_grad=True))
        self.bi_xy_std  = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(bi_xy_std, requires_grad=True))
        self.bi_rgb_std  = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor(bi_rgb_std, requires_grad=True))

    def forward(self, image, probmap):
        C, H, W = probmap.shape
        U = utils.unary_from_softmax(probmap)
        U = np.ascontiguousarray(U)
        image = np.ascontiguousarray(image)
        d = dcrf.DenseCRF2D(W, H, C)
        d.setUnaryEnergy(U)
        d.addPairwiseGaussian(sxy=self.pos_xy_std, compat=self.pos_w)
        d.addPairwiseBilateral(sxy=self.bi_xy_std, srgb=self.bi_rgb_std, rgbim=image, compat=self.bi_w )
        Q = d.inference(self.iter_max)
        Q = np.array(Q).reshape((C, H, W))
        return Q
```

Comment: The main issue I see here is the backward pass, and since you are using a third party library, this will probably be a big deal. Without it, you won't be able to update your parameters!

Comment: Any conversions from a torch tensor to a numpy array will necessarily break autograd, thus if any tensors are converted to numpy, or any tensors are `.detach`ed in the sequence of calculations from the parameter definition to the calculation of the loss value, then you won't be able to compute gradients for your parameters (i.e. backwards will fail to update `.grad` for your parameters). This includes whatever is happening in the `DenseCRF2D` class.

Comment: I think I understand, so the issue is what I return from the forward method is not going to be connected to the parameter tensor so can't compute the derivative of the loss wrt the parameters.

Comment: Does torch have a way to do this numerically, I don't mind if it runs slowly or on the CPU?

Comment: I don't see a way to do this without carefully going through `dcrf.DenseCRF2D` and seeing how it handles it's calculations. If you're lucky then `DenseCRF2D` was implemented in a way that is agnostic to whether the inputs are numpy arrays or tensors, so you could just use it. More likely you would need to reimplement or modify at least certain operations within that class to make it compatible with pytorch tensors. An alternative would be to define a custom backward, but this would mean you already know an explicit formula for the gradients of `DenseCRF2D.inference`